# how do i get the days of the week using kotlin in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, calendar

I'm trying to get the day number to put that number in a textView. for example, we know that today is Wednesday the 26th, knowing this information, I want to take this number "26" and put it inside a textView that will be displayed inside a screen that has a weekly calendar. so I try to help create a logic that tells me if it's Wednesday it returns the current day of the week (26), if I tell Thursday, it returns me (27) and so on for the entire week. tks. ;)

```
val diaDaSemana: DayOfWeek
    diaDaSemana.get(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)
    binding.txtNumeroQuarta = diaDaSemana.toString()
```

I'm trying this way to get the day.

calender image :

[image: calender image]

basically I just want the number informing the week, for example, I inform you that it's Wednesday, then you have to return me on the 26th so I can put it in the textView.

Comment: The reason what you did didn't work is that your `val day` is the result of calling `calendar.add` which doesn't return anything, so it just has a value of `kotlin.Unit`. But I  don't understand from your description exactly what you're trying to do so I'm not sure what else to tell you. The Calendar class is obsolete and you should use LocalDate instead. You got bitten because Calendar is a mutable class, one of its numerous shortcomings.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is take the days of the week and add them to a weekly calendar on a mobile screen. For example, today is the 26th, so I want to take '26' and put it inside the textView according to the day of the week.

Comment: add every day of the week to the weekly calendar https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw89K.jpg

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to explain by taking a step back and just describing the exact data you need. For example, "I want to determine what day of the week is the first day of a month in a given year."

Comment: it's a weekly calendar I only look for the days of the current week, for example, this week it goes from the 23rd to the 29th, so I want to display: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, using native mobile resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with LocalDate. From a given date (I set it to today by default in the example code), find the first day of the week by using `TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame` to get the most recent Sunday. Then use another TemporalAdjuster to get next occurrence of the input day of the week.

```
fun DayOfWeek.dayOfMonth(dateInWeek: LocalDate = LocalDate.now()): Int {
    val firstDateOfWeek = dateInWeek.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
    val dateOfDayOfWeek = firstDateOfWeek.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(this))
    return dateOfDayOfWeek.dayOfMonth
}

// ...

binding.txtNumeroQuarta = DayOfWeek.THURSDAY.dayOfMonth().toString()
```

Comment: nice bro, it worked very well, thanks it was exactly what I wanted tks

Comment: displayed exactly the numbers of that week in the weekly calendar, which are: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 and 29

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for clarifying the explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
val day = Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH.toString()
binding.txtNumeroTerca.text = day
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it didn't return the current date, but the date of the beginning of the month

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand. Can you give an example of the expected result?

Comment: it did not return the date I expected, for example, I expected it to return the 26th, which is today, but it returned the 3rd

Comment: updated my answer from Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK to Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH

Answer (score 0):

It is because add() method returns nothing. If you want to get day of month, try something like that:

```
val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.TUESDAY)
val day= calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

binding.txtNumeroTerca.text = day.toString()
```

And I recommend using numbers in add() method than code of week days.

Comment: I tried this way to show the current day, but it showed me a nonsense day, see : https://imgur.com/a/h4A0L6j (it was supposed to show 26 which is today)

Comment: Problem may be adding days. First day in java is Sunday and last is Saturday, so value of Sunday is 1 and Saturday is 6. If you are adding days dependly on dayweek it seems to be problem. If today is 26 and you add Wednesday code which is 4 it returns 30.